# How to load multiple ".RData" in R and them combine as mcmc list?

Tags: r, load

Suppose I have multiple `.RData` file in a folder like

```
sample 1.RData
sample 2.RData
sample 3.RData
sample 4.RData
sample 5.RData
sample 6.RData
sample 7.RData
sample 8.RData
```

I would like to load all of them and save them as `sample_list=mcmc.list( list( mcmc(sample1), mcmc(sample2),
mcmc(sample3),mcmc(sample4),mcmc(sample5),mcmc(sample6),mcmc(sample7),mcmc(sample8)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `load` all the objects into the global env after extracting the object names , then loop over the `list`, apply `mcmc` individually on the `list` elements and then wrap with the `mcmc.list`

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "^sample\\s*\\d+\\.RData$")
mcmc.list(lapply(files, function(dat) mcmc(get(load(dat))))
```